# Notice: Constant _IDIOMA already defined

Tags: php

Estoy intentando llevar a local un proyecto (mal hecho) funcional pero para seguir haciendo cosas tengo que trabajar en local.

La cosa es que al compilar me sale este error que no entiendo de donde viene.

El programa tiene traducciones con `lang` y me da este problema al cargar con todas las constantes predefinidas para su traducción:

```
 Notice: Constant _IDIOMA already defined in C:\wamp64\www\web\lang\lang-esp.php on line 34
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  362672  {main}( )   ...\data_caso.php:0
2   0.0000  393352  include( 'C:\wamp64\www\web\cop_up_data_caso.php' ) ...\data_caso.php:3
3   0.0000  461400  include( 'C:\wamp64\www\web\cop_top.php' )  ...\cop_up_data_caso.php:181
4   0.0000  463208  include( 'C:\wamp64\www\web\controllers\procesar_idioma.php' )  ...\cop_top.php:6
5   0.0156  575696  include( 'C:\wamp64\www\web\lang\lang-esp.php' )    ...\procesar_idioma.php:8
6   0.0156  575760  define ( )  ...\lang-esp.php:34
```

el proceso del idioma le tengo así

```
<?php

    switch ($_SESSION["idioma"]) {

      case 'en':
           include './lang/lang-eng.php';
           break;
      case 'es':
           include './lang/lang-esp.php';
           break;
//      case 'fr':
//           include './lang/lang-fra.php';
//           break;
       default:
           include './lang/lang-eng.php';
           break;
    }


?>
```

y si pongo un var_dump me carga el idioma correctamente justo antes de darme las notice

Comment: Tal y como aparece en el mensaje, la constante ya está definida, se definiría en algún otro lado y no se permite duplicar la definición. ¿Podrías mirar en otros archivos PHP en cuál la estás definiendo también?

Comment: el tema es que me da error al ponerlo en local, esta definido _IDIOMA en lang-esp.php y lang-eng.php

Comment: entiendo que no funciona la función que hace que cargue el que toca y carga los dos a la vez

Comment: ¿Y en algún sitio debes elegir entre importar un archivo u otro para seleccionar el idioma? Si es así, debes evitar importar ambos. ¿En local dices que funciona y en un servidor remoto no? ¿Al revés? Cuenta más sobre la versión de PHP que tienes en local y en remoto y qué más cambios hay entre ambos entornos.

Comment: funciona en servidor remoto donde tengo php 7.0 y el local en apache tengo también php 7.0, la del remoto es una nas.

Comment: Obviamente algo cambia entre entornos. ¿Qué framework usas? ¿Puedes compartir el código del controlador y/o del servicio que carga los lenguajes?

Comment: ¿El "proceso de idioma" lo tienes en una función o en algún sitio que pueda ser llamado en múltiples ocasiones? Como **parche** te recomendaría cambiar el `switch ($_SESSION["idioma"])` por `switch (!defined('_IDIOMA') && $_SESSION["idioma"])` o bien los `include` por `include_once`.

Comment: framework? :) he llegado y me he encontrado php nativo, ya podía tener un mvc. l Viene de la pantalla anterior el idioma y a partir de ahí hace el include, con el include_once, se solventó, ese problema, gracias

Comment: Como dije, usar `include_once` es un parche al código, no la solución. Por algún motivo estás pasando dos veces (o más) por el mismo código, habría que averiguar por qué y, viendo que no usas framework, habría que revisar todo el código para ver dónde está repitiendo lag llamadas.

Comment: te podría sacar una foto del orden del código para que me entendieras

Comment: gracias por todo

Comment: Si quieres solucionar la raíz del problema [continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97966/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-mantamusica) y allí hacemos las pruebas necesarias para detectar el motivo por el que el código se ejecuta múltiples veces.